# @magentoDbIsolation triggers fatal errors

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

When running integration tests for my custom Magento module, usage of the annotation `@magentoDbIsolation` causes this error to be logged:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@magentoDBIsolation" in method \<module>\Test\Integration\Test::testXXXX() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in /var/vstsagent/_work/14/a/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:54
```

I have Magento `2.3-develop` branch installed locally. I'm running PHP 7.2.10 and PHPUnit 6.5.14.

I can run Magento's core tests (which have this annotation) without issue - so what might this be? Are there some cases where adding `@magentoDBIsolation enabled` is not valid, based on the behaviour of the test? Could this cause the above error?

Note, there are some tests in this module which use the annotation, and do not trigger an error. I just can't understand why some would fail and others not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have an typo in the annotation, correct value should be `@magentoDbIsolation`

Comment: It _is_ an answer because the question is, "why is this not working" and the answer could potentially be "I've spelled it wrong". Investigating.